# What public information in a profile does the G+ People search API look into when performing a search?

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-people-api, google-apis-explorer

I am talking about the functionality of the API that can be tested here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search

I used to think it looks into all the public fields of a profile ("Specify a query string for full text search of public text in all profiles."), but it seems you can't search by email, telephone or some of the education and work information (even if the expected resulting profiles make this information public).

So my question is, what public data **does** this search use to retrieve its results? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: I doubt it. The results include people who are not my contacts.

Answer (score 0):

[People: search](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search)

> query  string  Specify a query string for full text search of public text in all profiles.

I found a random user. [here](https://plus.google.com/+GDesignCreative)  I picked this guy because he had a lot of text in his profile.

Lets search on "gdesignart"  This is part of his display name.

```
{
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"Sh4n9u6EtD24TM0RmWv7jTXojqc/W9DoYLbchkxsXWI_HhuWV6G7lJY\"",
   "objectType": "person",
   "id": "116044052555068441384",
   "displayName": "Marcello Ghirardi (gdesignart)",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/116044052555068441384",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-IqYeJSv07cI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAPM/yw8nbO0Ho6g/photo.jpg?sz=50"
   }
```

Works fine and I get a response.

Now lets try some text from his `tagline` or `introduction` arguably we could say this `qualifies` as **public text** on his profile.

I tried the following

1. G-Design®
2. è un brand
3. Pollutre of different world

None worked. If you look at the response the only thing in the response is the users display name.   From my experience with other google APIs I can tell you that I don't think its going to let you search on any field that is not part of its response.   So you are only going to be searching on DisplayName.  For the fun of it I searched on his ID that didn't return anything either.

Answer: search is on display name only.

I would recommend adding this as a feature request if you link it here I will happily add my name to it.  [Google plus issue forum](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list)

Comment: While your search examples are correct, it appears I can search by education for example (but only the latest school-type organization publicly listed on one's profile). The same seems to be true about work-type organizations.
You can search "saint sava national college", for instance, and you can see the results. 
These things are not included in the concise results the search returns, they are "public text". This is the reason of my confusion: some public text is searchable but some is not.

Comment: I've already opened an issue on this subject on the forum as an enhancement request for documentation (it would be quite useful)
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1450

Comment: It could also depend upon what the user has set as public.    If the data isn't set to public your not going to be able to search on it.

Comment: I am aware of that. But some info is not searchable even if made public (such as email, phone, and even some work and education). I tested it on my profile (besides others). If I search "<my_name> <my_most_recent_school_organization>", my profile shows up. But if I search "<my_name> <my_second_most_recent_school_organization>", then no result is found.
Here is my profile: https://plus.google.com/u/0/108156168463894160116 (all education is public). The two examples I was talking about are "Catalin Florea Polytechnic University" and "Catalin Florea Saint Sava ".

Comment: that's kind of cool I got this guy to by searching on his location https://plus.google.com/116421826693154526559

Comment: The API is pretty nice, indeed. It's a shame we don't know for sure what we can search by, though.